# Selenium is returning empty text for elements that definitely have ID

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)  # wait 5 seconds

#username_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="APjFqb"]')
#or
username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'APjFqb')


element_text = username_field.text
print("Element Text:", element_text)
```

[image: Screenshot of the inspected elements]

**EDIT**

[image]

I would need to extract "Please enter valid Mobile Number or Email Address"

Code Used:

```
driver.get("https://www.ixambee.com/login")
username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mobile_alert_valid')
element_text = username_field.text
print("Element Text:", element_text)

driver.quit()
```

I'm trying to extract the text from the element with attribute `id=mobile_alert_valid`. I don't understand why it's not returning the text values especially when I can see that it contains text with dev tools.

> selenium Version: 4.15.2

Comment: What text value are you expecting it to return?

Comment: @Shawn, I made some EDITS, please have a look. wanted to extract "Please enter valid Mobile Number or Email Address" from the element having ID=mobile_alert_valid

Comment: Check the updated answer now and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New solution as per the edited question:**
You need to first ensure the desired message is displayed on the screen. You can do that by entering an invalid email in the text box and by clicking <kbd>Next</kbd> button.

**Working code with in-line explanation:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.ixambee.com/login")

# create wait object which wait for 15s based on the condition
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# Enter invalid email in the text box and click Next button so that the desired message displays on screen
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mbnumber"))).send_keys("invalidemail")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Next']"))).click()

# Locate the message, capture it and print it
username_field =  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='number_div']//small[@id='mobile_alert_valid']")))
element_text = username_field.text
print("Element Text:", element_text)
```

**Console output:**

```
Element Text: Please enter valid Mobile Number or Email Address

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using **get_attribute**. It worked for me

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(2)
print(driver.title)
username_element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[@id="APjFqb"]')
username_element.send_keys('Nur')
time.sleep(3)
#priting value
latest_value = username_element.get_attribute('value')
print(f'User Name: {latest_value}')
```

[image: Output]